# How to setup socket.io server in NextJS13.4.19 app router

Tags: typescript, next.js, socket.io

I am working on NextJS/TypeScript project.
"next" version is 13.4.19

I made socket.ts file in app/api folder.

And edited like:

```
import type { Server as HTTPServer } from 'http'
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import type { Socket as NetSocket } from 'net'
import type { Server as IOServer } from 'socket.io'
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

interface SocketServer extends HTTPServer {
  io?: IOServer | undefined
}

interface SocketWithIO extends NetSocket {
  server: SocketServer
}

interface NextApiResponseWithSocket extends NextApiResponse {
  socket: SocketWithIO
}

const SocketHandler = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponseWithSocket) => {
  if (res.socket.server.io) {
    console.log('Socket is already running.')
  } else {
    console.log('Socket is initializing...')

    const io = new Server(res.socket.server)
    res.socket.server.io = io

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      socket.on('input-change', (msg) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('update-input', msg)
      })
    })
  }
  res.end()
}

export default SocketHandler
```

And dashboard page component is below:

```
'use client'
import { FC, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import io from "socket.io-client";

import type { ChangeEvent } from 'react'
import type { Socket } from 'socket.io-client'

let socket: undefined | Socket

export const DashboardMessagesPage: FC = () => {
  const [isContactInfoOpened, setIsContactInfoOpened] = useState(false);
  const [isRightSearchWidgetOpened, setIsRightSearchWidgetOpened] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    socketInitializer()
  }, [])

  const socketInitializer = async () => {
    await fetch('/api/socket');
    socket = io()

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('connected')
    })

    socket.on('update-input', (msg) => {
      // setInput(msg)
      console.log('connected')
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
   ... ... ...
    </>
  )
}
```

Then I ran the project, but socket server is not working.
And it says like below:

```
Warning: Detected multiple renderers concurrently rendering the same context provider. This is currently unsupported.
    at PathnameContextProviderAdapter (E:\My projects\Alexis Chattersite project\chattersite\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\adapters.js:84:11)
    at AppContainer (E:\My projects\Alexis Chattersite project\chattersite\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:323:29)
    at AppContainerWithIsomorphicFiberStructure (E:\My projects\Alexis Chattersite project\chattersite\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:359:57)
    at div
    at Body (E:\My projects\Alexis Chattersite project\chattersite\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:659:21)
```

Also in web browser console, it says:

```
DashboardMessagesPage.tsx:22 
        
        
       GET http://localhost:3000/api/socket 404 (Not Found)
DashboardMessagesPage.tsx:23 
        
        
       GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OqoVHtC 404 (Not Found)
```

Please help me!

I tried to run socket.io server for my chatting project,
but it is not working.